# How to Map Method parameter in ngFor , method is also inside the array for the each element

Tags: angular

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let btn of btns">
    <button class="btn me-4 {{btn.class}}" [title]="btn.title" #btn (click)="btn.functionToCall(btn,'hello')">
      {{btn.name}}
    </button>
  </ng-container>
```

i am looping the buttons array and inside the button data i passed the method it self

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  PrintFour() {
    console.log("four");
  }
  PrintThree() {
    console.log("three");

  }
  PrintTwo() {
    console.log("two");

  }
  PrintHello(data?: string) {
    console.log("hello is printed");
    if (data)
      console.log(data);
  }

  printParamert1(btn: HTMLButtonElement) {
    btn.innerHTML = "1 is clicked"
  }

  printParamert2(btn: HTMLButtonElement) {
    btn.innerHTML = "2 is clicked"
  }
  btns: Array<any> = [

    { "name": "one", "title": "one", "functionToCall": this.PrintHello, "class": "btn-success" },
    { "name": "two", "title": "two", "functionToCall": this.PrintTwo, "class": "btn-danger" },
    { "name": "three", "title": "three", "functionToCall": this.PrintThree, "class": "btn-info" },
    { "name": "four", "title": "four", "functionToCall": this.PrintFour, "class": "btn-secondary" },
    { "name": "five", "title": "five", "functionToCall": this.printParamert1, "class": "btn-secondary" },
    { "name": "six", "title": "siz", "functionToCall": this.printParamert2, "class": "btn-secondary" },


  ]
}
```

Here i am confused some method is containing the parameter , with different different type, and i am calling it with two parameter based on type i thought it will call but not

i also created stackblits example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8dsrxy?file=src/app/app.component.ts

i just want to know How i can pass the parameters to appropriate method

Comment: You don't need to pass the btn object as the first parameter to `functionToCall`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it correctly, the issue is that you are using the same variable name, so it's not really picking up the html element. Just give a different template variable name and it should work.

```
<button class="btn me-4 {{btn.class}}" [title]="btn.title" #btnElement (click)="btn.functionToCall(btnElement ,'hello')">
  {{btn.name}}
</button>
```